# Callback when ngRepeat/ngIf mutates DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a directive that needs to execute a callback function whenever its DOM subtree is mutated (by ngIf or ngRepeat for instance).

The directive is ideally able to be easily inserted to templates I have already made, which rules out putting an ng-init. I've looked at the documentation, and neither ngRepeat or ngIf seem to have any events. Additionally, it seems that most of the browser DOM events have been depreciated as well.

I would use a watch, but I can't think of an expression that will work, as jQuery returns a new object every time and the length of .children() might be unchanged through mutation if ngRepeat removes and inserts a node in the same $digest.

Any suggestions on how to detect any DOM subtree mutation entirely from a template-less directive?

EDIT: For more detail, I have multiple tables that have rows of data inserted with ngRepeat. Whenever a row is inserted, if the table has a resize directive, I need to add CSS to it. The resize directive is general enough to go on every table without needing any input, so I would prefer to not have to add ngInits to all the ngRepeat elements.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Suggest you provide a higher level overview of what you are needing to accomplish and how jQuery is being used. One helpful part of `ng-repeat` that might help is child scopes that are created and properties like `$last`

Comment: Is there an event for ngRepeat creates a scope? I don't think there is, but angulars documentation is sometimes lacking. There is one for when it destroys a scope ($destroy), and I could combine that event with tracking the amount of children in order to always detect ngRepeat changes, but that takes a lot of work.

Comment: in directive try `if(scope.$last){ /* code that needs all repeat elements complete*/}`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution that will usually work in situations like this, Angular recompiles all the repeated elements, even if they were already present. Thus the actual DOMNode objects are different, so you can just watch a DOMNode.